# Getting the location of a .tt file in T4

Tags: c#, .net, t4

Using T4 I want to generate some code based on examining what files are in a directory relative to the template file being executed.

Is there a way in c# to identify what the path of the current template file is?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- You need to set the `hostspecific="true"` property of the `<#@ template` directive to `True`.
- This will make T4 generate a special property called `Host`, which gives you access to `ResolvePath` method and `TemplateFile` property.

  - `Host` is of type [`ITextTemplatingEngineHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.itexttemplatingenginehost?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).
  - [`TemplateFile` is a `String` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.itexttemplatingenginehost.templatefile?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TextTemplating_ITextTemplatingEngineHost_TemplateFile) which is typically the file-system path of the `.tt` file - however other T4 hosts (i.e. hosts other than Visual Studio) which may load a T4 file in-memory or otherwise may return some other value as the template file doesn't exist on-disk.
- You can find details here: [http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-template-directive/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315051742/http://olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-template-directive/)

For example:

```
<#@ template hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#
    ITextTemplatingEngineHost t4Host = this.Host;
    FileInfo t4FileInfo = new FileInfo( t4Host.TemplateFile );
#>

// This file generated by <#= t4FileInfo.FullName #>
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to ask you whether your code is still (in 2015) only one existing solution. I found simpler and in run-time functional piece of code  [var namespaceName = System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.LogicalGetData("NamespaceHint") as string;] but this code does not work when debugging T4 template (tested in VS 2012).

Comment: I'm confused how this is simpler than setting the hostspecific flag... There are always going to be many possible solutions, but enabling the Host property gives you a lot of functionality to simplify output file management.